# Prevent command from stopping when pressing CTRL+C

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

So, I was playing some Zork 1 and I went to copy some text to show a friend of mine, but I accidentally forgot to hold the shift key when pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. This stopped the command and I lost my Zork data...

Is there some sort of "helpful" tip out their that I can use to prevent stopping the command when press the keys <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

Note that Zork is run inside of the terminal.  It's a terminal-based game in which you give commands to perform different actions.

Comment: So you want Ctrl + c to prevent terminatting all applications altogether? That might be disastrous in future though.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends the character `^C` (byte value 3). This causes the terminal to send the [SIGINT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_(POSIX)#SIGINT) signal to the program running in the foreground¹. The conventional action for this signal is to interrupt the current command: programs designed to process successive commands go back to their toplevel prompt, while programs designed as a single batch command or a continuous interaction exit. Evidently the program you're using was designed according to the second model.

This signal-sending key is a feature of the general terminal interface in the kernel, shared by all terminal emulators and real physical terminals. You can configure which key sends this signal, as well as other keys (most notably <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> sending [SIGSTOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSTOP#SIGSTOP) to suspend the foreground program) with the [`stty`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/stty.1.html) command. To switch the key for SIGINT to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> (in the current terminal):

```
stty intr '^_'
```

To disable it altogether:

```
stty intr ''
```

To reset all settings to the default:

```
stty sane
```

The key cannot be an arbitrary key combination, it has to be a single byte value. The `stty` setting can be overridden by programs — some programs (especially full-screen text mode programs) do their own keyboard shortcut processing.

¹  <sub>[More precisely](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap11.html#tag_11_01_09), to all the processes in the [foreground](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_183) [process group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_290) for which the terminal is the [controlling terminal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_114).</sub>

Answer (score 32):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> sends an interrupt signal (`SIGINT`, which is signal number 2) to the job in the foreground. You can disable this by "trapping" the signal using the `trap '' 2` command before starting Zork.

Re-enable <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (untrap `SIGINT`) with `trap 2`.

**Tip**: you could add something like this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias zork="(trap '' 2 && cd ~/path/to/zork/ && frotz ZORK1.DAT)"
```

This way you will never forget to disable and re-enable the signal and it's easier to start the game by just typing `zork` in the terminal.

**Note**: you can use the signal name instead of the number if it's more convenient for you, i.e. `trap '' sigint` or `trap '' int`. I'm just used to using the numbers, e.g. in `kill -9` and such.